# Center a button inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, center

I'm having trouble centering a button inside a DIV.

The result I get currently is:

[image: Button in a div]

The HTML is:

```
<div id="buttonDiv">
<div class="button">
<button type="submit" onClick="setSid()">Click here to Start Test</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS consists of:

```
#buttonDiv {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border-bottom-width:1px;
        border-top-width:1px;
        border-right-width:1px;
        border-left-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
}

.button {
     display:table-cell;
     align-content:center;
     vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

I believe this route should work for text but doesn't appear to work for the button. I've tried adding the class directly to the button with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add text-align center to the parent container, the button will center horizontally. Then you can use the *top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);* trick to center vertically.

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttonDiv">
<button type="submit" onClick="setSid()">Click here to Start Test</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#buttonDiv {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border-bottom-width:1px;
        border-top-width:1px;
        border-right-width:1px;
        border-left-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
        text-align:center;
}

button {
   position:relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[jsfiddle option 1](http://jsfiddle.net/gc70wzL5/)

**EDIT BELOW**

If you need to keep the '.button' div, you can just move the *top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);* to that class.

HTML

```
<div id="buttonDiv">
    <div class="button">
         <button type="submit" onClick="setSid()">Click here to Start Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#buttonDiv {
   position: fixed;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -100px 0px 0px -100px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   text-align:center;
}
.button {
   position:relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[jsfiddle option 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gc70wzL5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **line-height** of the box to its height; Then display the button as the **inline** element and add **text-align:center**

```css
#buttonDiv {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border-bottom-width:1px;
        border-top-width:1px;
        border-right-width:1px;
        border-left-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
  line-height:200px;
  text-align:center;
}

.button {
     display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonDiv">
<div class="button">
<button type="submit" onClick="setSid()">Click here to Start Test</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

CSS:

```
#buttonDiv {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        padding: 78px 0;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
}

.button {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: no luck I'm afraid. The buttonDiv uses the width and height parameters to center the box perfectly in the center. Now I just need the button centered within that DIV